# IIS Request monitor is not showing current request on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

Request monitor is enabled

[image: Please check the image of the Request monitor enabled on the server]

but IIS > Worker Processes not showing the Current Requests

[image: as shown in the image]

Can someone guide me on how can i make it work to view all HTTP requests? Thanks!

Comment: [sf] might be a better place to ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Current Requests only shows requests that are in progress. You need to check whether there is any request executing under the current application pool. It is usually used to check for broken or slow requests, or when requests take a long time to process. If you want to view all HTTP requests, You can try to use some tools to capture all request like network monitor and fiddler.